# Ember.js right way of records creation

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Cheers! I have models structure like this:

```
App.Foo = DS.Model.extend({
  bars: DS.hasMany('App.Bar')
});

App.Bar = DS.Model.extend({
  number: DS.attr('number'),
  foo: DS.belongsTo('App.Foo')
});
```

Is it ok to create `App.Bar` record first? And if yes, then how to create `App.Foo` in future and associate already existing Bars records to it in right way? I just want to know, if there something like 'ember-way' in such situations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it ok to create App.Bar record first?

Yes.

> if yes, then how to create App.Foo in future and associate already existing Bars records to it in right way?

```
bar = store.createRecord(App.Bar);
store.commit();

//later
foo = store.createRecord(App.Foo);
store.commit();

//later
foo.get('bars').addObject(comment);
store.commit();
```

For some more detailed examples see [one-to-many-relationship-tests](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/tests/integration/relationships/one_to_many_relationships_test.js)

Comment: Is it necessary to foo and bar be in one transaction?

Comment: For now they actually need to be in separate transactions. There is an open pull-request that would add support for creating parent and child-records in the same transaction - see https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/440